# Fabric, retrieving result of a bash command into a python variable

Tags: python, bash, fabric

I would like to store the result of a command in a variable.

By instance running :  `a = sudo("ls -l my_filename | awk '{print $11}'")`

How could I achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a = sudo("ls -l my_filename | awk '{print $11}'", capture=True )
```